# Certificate imported to trusted root is placed under Intermediate CA

Tags: powershell, certificate

I try to import certificate in powershell as the following

```
Import-PfxCertificate -FilePath "$certFolder\$certFile" -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\Root -Password $securedPassword
```

The command run without any errors but the certificate is placed under Intermediate CAs with the information that CA root is not trusted.

When I import the same certificate manually with the option checked "Automatically select the certificate store..." it is placed properly under the Trusted CAs.

What do I miss while importing the certificate automatically?

Comment: `Cert:\LocalMachine\Root` -> `Cert:\LocalMachine\TrustedPeople`?

Comment: Nope. Actually I've tried all stores under localMachine - same effect

Comment: The PKI cmdlets kinda... suck - only real way to do this properly (AFAIK) is to manually import the pfx into a `X509Certificate2Collection` object, traverse the chain and then manually installing the leaf into MY, intermediates into Intermediate CAs and the root into ROOT